# Jetty server can't load some class for some jsp after jetty server running a time

Tags: time, jetty

We have an application running on stand alone jetty server, the server version is 6.1.20. After starting the application, it runs well for a period of time. But after some time(it is not definitive), some jsp page couldn't open in the application excepting restarting the jetty server.

Any one encounter this problem?

The exception is:

```
Nested in org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6034: Unable to load class for JSP:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.jsp.XXX.XXX_jsp
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.findClass(JasperLoader.java:204)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:190)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:122)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:639)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:192)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:372)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:112)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:249)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:736)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:396)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:350)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:502)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:78)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:77)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1153)
        at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:264)
        at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

these sorts of issues are typically related to some sort of sweeping process cleaning out the temp directory where jetty has unpacked a webapp

Comment: But only for some jsp page, and its class file is existed in /tmp/JettyXXXXXX.

If it is due to some sort of sweping process cleaning out the temp directory, then why other jsp pages can open except one. The one which could not open is not specific, it may be any jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some tmp-directory clean up processes only delete certain files that have not been accessed for a specified time.

I had this same problem and found out that on my CentOS 5.9, [tmpwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch) was deleting files that had not been accessed in 10 days from the tmp directory. That's why some jsp's were working and some not.

I fixed the problem by excluding the Jetty tmp folder from tmpwatch process.